# uploading large files (mp4) to IIS 7.5 gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, iis-7.5

I made a website on which i need to be able to upload video files and it has worked for quite a while. However after a while it just stopped working and now it will give me the following IIS error message when i upload a video. Images do work (possibly due to their smaller size). I use an html form with PHP server sided script to upload.

[image]

I have already set the user permissions for the entire inetpub to allow all actions for the IIS user.

If you have any idea what it could be PLEASE tell me, have been trying to fix this for weeks now.

**PHP settings:**

upload_max_filesize = 2048M

post_max_size = 2048M

max_input_time = 3000

max_execution_time = 3000

file_uploads = On

default_socket_timeout = 3000

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a lot of things over the past 2 months but couldn't find a way to solve this so i decided to work around the problem using [plupload](http://plupload.com/), an upload script that chunks the big file. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

please set 
upload_max_filesize=size in mb
post_max_size=size in mb

in php ini file

Comment: added all the values that are related to uploads